# How to determine the Tipping Point of which Physical Join Operator gets used to process a query?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016, join, performance-tuning

I've been noticing some strange occurrences lately on my development SQL Server instance where the **Nested Loops** Physical Join Operator is used when a **Hash Join** would be much more efficient, within a multitude of different queries on my server. One example I encountered was where the two datasets are in the thousands and millions, and producing resultant datasets in the billions after joined.

Evidently using the query hint `HASH JOIN` improves the performance in each case so far, but I'm trying to understand what factors are generally / globally involved that affect the tipping point of which physical join operator is used.

I'm starting to wonder if my database, the SQL Server instance, or the server provisioned for it are potentially configured in an unusual way. (I'm thinking this for a number of other performance oddities I've run into so far as well, but I'm not quite ready yet at trying to determine the root cause.)

So, I'm just wondering what factors are used to determine the tipping point of which physical join operator is used, and how can I determine what the value of that tipping point is in my SQL Server instance? My understanding is it's not a fixed value as briefly mentioned in [this article on adaptive join regression](https://orderbyselectnull.com/2017/10/03/an-adaptive-join-regression/).

> **Traditional Tipping Point**:
> There’s a tipping point where the plan will change from a hash join to
> a loop join if we filter out a single additional row. On my machine,
> the tipping point is between 48295 and 48296 rows

Hopefully to provide some context, below is my most recent example of the issue I experienced.

This is the anonymized (sorry) [actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1uxk4q7F) for the slow query in my DEV server.

You'll notice the first operator just before the `SELECT` is a `Nested Loops` operator. That operator and the bottom arrow / half of the execution plan is where the issue stems from:
[image: Nested Loops]

Starting from the bottom right most set of operators in the execution plan, there's a lot of fat arrows with cardinalities in the millions to billions:
[image: 2.8 Billion Rows Cardinality]

The biggest table (`Object5`) only has ~2 million rows in it. But this `Nested Loops` join causes its clustered index to be iterated about 2,143 times which results in a cardinality of about 2.8 billion:
[image]

This is anonymized (sorry again) [actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry2bp7c7t) for the fast query when I use a `Hash Join` (and is also almost exactly what my PROD server naturally chooses as an execution plan even without using the `Hash Join` query hint).

Notice the `Hash Match` 4 operators to the right of the `SELECT` operator (as opposed to `Nested Loops`):

[image: Hash Match Fast]

Also noticed a lot less fat arrows, and the clustered index seek (`Object4` now) operator all the way on the bottom right results in only ~1.3 million rows instead of ~2.8 billion rows:
[image: Lot Smaller Cardinality]

At the end of the day, this query only returns about 7,000 rows and takes about 1.5 hours when it's using that first `Nested Loops` operator. But if I explicitly change the join that causes that operator to be a `Hash Join` then the query returns in 5 seconds.

Comment: That article refers to a specific tipping point for a specific query, not a generalized thing, it's much more complicated than that. Another relevant article https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/05/no-you-cant-calculate-the-tipping-point-with-simple-percentages/. For your particular query, you may want to update statistics and/or use `option (recompile)` and/or rewrite the query

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the Brent Ozar article and thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately none of the cases I've run into so far have been a statistics problem or one that can be solved by `RECOMPILE` hints. Every time I've checked the statistics on my tables at play, they're pretty spot on (if not exactly correct). But that being said, recurring significant cardinality estimates issues on *normal* queries has been a thing I've also been battling on this server. Not sure why so many issues when not really doing much out of the ordinary.